# How to avoid a really long list of function parameters in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, parameters, scope

My problem is that I have lots of functions with VERY long lists of function parameters such as this one:

```
function select_items($con,$type,$id_item,$item_timestamp,$item_source_url,$item_type,$item_status,$item_blogged_status,$item_viewcount,$item_language,$item_difficulty,$item_sharecount,$item_pincount,$item_commentcount,$item_mainpage,$item_image_width,$item_image_height,$item_image_color,$item_modtime,$order,$start,$limit,$keyword,$language,$id_author,$id_sub_category,$id_category,$id_tag,$id_user){ ... }
```

As you can see its super long and (of course) very hard to maintain. Sometimes I need all of the variables to construct a super complex sql query, but sometimes I just use 1 or 2 of them.  Is there a way to avoid this colossal list of parameters? For example with some strict / special naming convention ?

So basically I need something like this:

```
$strictly_the_same_param_name="It's working!";

echo hello($strictly_the_same_param_name);


function hello()  //<- no, or flexible list of variables
{
     return $strictly_the_same_param_name; // but still able to recognize the incoming value        
}

// outputs: It's working!
```

I thought about using $_GLOBALs / global or $_SESSIONs to solve this problem but it doesn't seems really professional to me. Or is it?

Comment: Use an associative array as the parameter

Comment: Use an Array instead,

Comment: Or see [Example 13 in this PHP Manual Page](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) if you are using PHP > 5.6

Comment: Globals are normally a bad idea, for many reasons

Comment: Your function is probably too complex, period. If most of those parameters are optional, that probably means you have a ton of `if..else` statements in there too, which is simply bad. The only way to solve that it with *proper software engineering*, breaking functionality down into separate functions/objects/composeable objects/whatnot.

Comment: I'd go with a dedicated `ItemSearchQuery` class rather than an array, since it would provide some type-safety, but yes, passing a single parameter that can encapsulate all of the possible search parameters is the way to go. If the first argument `$con` is actually a connection variable, you should probably keep that separate.

Comment: @deceze Thank you! I know it's complex :) I have tons of  `switch..case` statements in my function, because this is my SQL search query "constructor", which means: if a condition sets it will add extra `AND` conditions and `LEFT JOIN`s to a basic select query. This way, if I need something simple, I won't spam my result set with tons of unneeded data, joins & columns. I thought it was a clever time & resource saving idea.. but maybe not :) But I'm just a beginner - so opinions and helpful comments are more than welcome!

Comment: iainn, RiggsFolly & Eddie :  Thank you so much,  your comment was really helpful!

@iainn : Yes, $con is a connection variable :) Thank you !

Comment: So, yeah, you probably want something like a *query builder*, e.g. `$builder->select('column1')->where('foo', 'bar')->and(...)->...`. Each function call here just does very little, accepts only one or two parameters, and keeps it simple. But that requires some understanding of objects and architecture…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a first step, as you said, sometimes you need to call the function with only 2 args, you can set default values to your arguments in the declaration of your function. This will allow you to call your function with only 2 args out of 25.

For example:

```
function foo($mandatory_arg1, $optional_arg = null, $opt_arg2 = "blog_post") {
    // do something
}
```

In a second step, you can use, and especially for that case, arrays, it will be way more simple:

```
function foo(Array $params) {
    // then here test your keys / values
}
```

In a third step, you can also use [Variable-length argument lists](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) (search in the page "..."):

```
function sum(...$numbers) {
    $acc = 0;
    foreach ($numbers as $n) {
        $acc += $n;
    }
    return $acc;
}
```

But ultimately, I think you should use objects to handle such things ;)

Comment: Thank you @WizardNx , this was super helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can try use `...` token:

```
$strictly_the_same_param_name= ["It's working!"];

echo hello($strictly_the_same_param_name);


function hello(...$args)  //<- no, or flexible list of variables
{
    if ( is_array( $args ) {
    $key = array_search( 'What you need', $args );
         if ( $key !== false ) {
             return $args[$key];
         }
    }
    return 'Default value or something else';
}
```